# Replacing value with different strings

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i'm having a problem with my database. I have the folowing:

```
create table book
(
    name_b varchaR(50) primary key,
    typee varchaR(50) not null,
    nmbr integer unique not null,
    yeare numeric(4,0) default null,
)

create table story
(
    id integer identity(1,1) primary key,
    name_s varchar(100) not null,
    chars varchar(100) not null,
    code varchaR(200) null,
    artist varchar(100) default null,
    argument varchar(100) default null,
    book_ref_name varchar(50) references book(name_b),
    book_ref_nmbr integer references book(nmbr)
)

insert into story values
('StoryName1','StoryChars1',null,default,default,'BookName1',13),
('StoryName2','StoryChars2',null,default,default,'BookName2',35),
('StoryName3','StoryChars3',null,default,default,'BookName3',125)

insert into book values
('BookName1','Type1',13,default),
('BookName2','Type2',35,default),
('BookName3','Type3',125,default)
```

what i want with this is the STORY.CODE to be replaced from NULL to a junction of strings for example imagine the first entry of the STORY table

```
('StoryName1','StoryChars1',null,default,default,'BookName1',13)
```

in this case i would like the STORY.CODE to be replaced with 'StoryName1-StoryChars1-BookName1-13'.

is this even possible? if it isn't whats the nearest possibility of something similar?
thx in advance

---

another doubt i have, how can i make a SELECT statement that selects * from STORY except the null fields. for example if a story has no argumentist/artist i dont want that field to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this via an `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE story
SET code = name_s + '-' + chars + '-' + book_ref_name + '-' + Convert(varchar(50), book_ref_nmbr)
WHERE code IS NULL
```

Via an `INSERT` you basically do something similar:

```
INSERT INTO story (fields,....)
SELECT 'StoryName1'
    ,'StoryChars1'
    ,IsNull(('StoryName1' + '-' + 'StoryChars1'+ '-' + 'BookName1' + '-' + Convert(varchar(50), 13), codevalue)
    ,default,default,'BookName1',13
```

Or you can use a `CASE`

```
INSERT INTO story (fields,....)
SELECT 'StoryName1'
    ,'StoryChars1'
    , CASE
      WHEN code Is Null
            THEN ('StoryName1' + '-' + 'StoryChars1'+ '-' + 'BookName1' + '-' + Convert(varchar(50), 13)
            ELSE yourcodevalue
      END
    ,default,default,'BookName1',13
```

As far as your second question regarding the `SELECT`, I think this is what you need

```
SELECT *
FROM story
WHERE artist is not Null
AND/OR argument is not Null
```

Comment: worked like a charm. is it possible to do this but only with the initials? like for BookName1 it will be BN1? and what about the other question in the end? what do you think of it?=

Comment: @FabioAbreu you can place whatever values you need in your insert/select. I updated my answer with your second question answered

Comment: please check the comments on jheep's answer for discussion about the 2nd question please =) thx in advance for the help in the 1st one

Comment: @FabioAbreu in regards to your second question, I would post it an another question to be answered. then the SO geniuses can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select CONCAT(artist, argument, etc) as joinedField
FROM Story
```

Based on your feedback I think you might be looking to concatenate several fields into one result.  If you wanted to get fancy with the nulls you should be able to put some conditional criteria in there.

Reference:
http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-concatenate.html

Comment: i meant to select * except the null fields. not to select * when artist and argumentist are not null.

Comment: So you don't want to have null values returned but you still want the row?  What are you trying to do with that result?  Are you trying to put multiple fields together into a single string from the select statement?  If so, that should be doable.

Comment: well imagine this `select * from story where name_s = 'StoryName1'` i want this select to be made but i dont want it to select the existing null fields

Comment: @FabioAbreu please see my updated answer, you can add whatever criteria you need for the WHERE clause and can add additional columns to the SELECT.

Comment: thats a CONCATENATE in MySql/Oracle, i'm using SQL Server 2008. i believe what you told me is made like this `Select artist+argument as joinedField
FROM Story`. however i dont want that. the results of the `select * from story where name_s = 'StoryName1'` would be the folowing [table](http://i.imgur.com/IgopW.png) but because those two fields are NULL i would want it to be like this [table](http://i.imgur.com/9XCGu.png) --------------------------- for the last table to show up that way i did this `select id,name_s,chars,code,book_ref_name,book_ref_nmbr from story where name_s = 'StoryName1'` _

Comment: I am not aware of any way to not return a column if a value in that column is null.